# Rendering HTML when request comes from browser or sending JSON dictionary when request comes from mobile

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, responsive-design, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a backend for an app that has both a web frontend (designed with bootstrap) and a mobile frontend (designed with Flutter).

I've been trying to understand the documentation for Django REST Framework about renderers, but I can't figure out how to deal with different types of requests (one from web and one from mobile, for example) without having two different functions for both platforms.

Is there a better way to do this than having a flag passed through the request that says whether the app is mobile or web, and returning a Response object or render object depending on that flag's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression that will split both actions such as below:

```
def mobile(request):
"""Return True if the request comes from a mobile device."""

    IS_MOBILE=re.compile(r".*(iphone|mobile|androidtouch)",re.IGNORECASE)

    if IS_MOBILE.match(request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: And would I need to return two different objects depending on that?

Comment: It is up to you, you could use `if mobile(your_request):` and `else:` then you decide what action you would like to do, in that case, returning a Response object or render object this is what you want I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use request headers to figure out what kind of device your request is coming from and return your data accordingly. More specifically the [User Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: And would I need to return a Response or a render depending on that?